# Unable to get Location in Genymotion VM

Tags: java, android, location, genymotion

I have created this simple application to get location. I'm using the genymotion virtual machine. I have enabled the GPS and installed correctly google play services. Unfortunately I'm not able to retrieve the location. Surely I have already added the right permission. There is something more that I should do?

```
package com.salvo.weather.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;


public class TodayActivity extends Activity
        implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    protected static final String TAG = "location-weather";

    protected Location mLastLocation;
    /**
     * Provides the entry point to Google Play services.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_today);

        // TODO: here get coordinates data and pass to Valley JsonObjectRetrieve

        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }

    /**
     * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
     */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_today, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * Runs when a GoogleApiClient object successfully connects.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices
                            .FusedLocationApi
                            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));
            Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No Location detected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        // The connection to Google Play services was lost for some reason. We call connect() to
        // attempt to re-establish the connection.
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        // Refer to the javadoc for ConnectionResult to see what error codes might be returned in
        // onConnectionFailed.
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion has a free feature for setting the location called "GPS" accessible via icon in the top right of the emulator window. Use the "GPS" icon to set your location via latitude/longitude or searchable map. Then, Location Services will find the location you specified.

Additional reported solutions include free scriptable Genyshell or paid Java API.